# Big bug in Oracle JDBC driver for mixed-case table/column names?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

This seems rather surprising, but I'm pretty sure we have found a significant bug in Oracle's JDBC driver (versions 12.1.0.2 and 11.2.0.4). Here's the schema:

```
create sequence MYSEQ increment by 1 start with 1 nocache;
create table "MixedCaseTable"(IDENT int);
```

Here's the Java code:

```
conn.prepareStatement("insert into \"MixedCaseTable\" " +
"(IDENT) VALUES (MYSEQ.nextval)",
new int[]{1});
```

Much to my surprise, this throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:459)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:384)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:767)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:539)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:235)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odscrarr.doODNY(T4C8Odscrarr.java:96)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doDescribeTable(T4CConnection.java:7555)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:12886)
at PStest.main(PStest.java:11)
```

If I use a different flavor of prepareStatement:

```
conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

that works fine.

If the table name is all caps (MYTABLE or even "MYTABLE"), that also works fine.

This problem can be reproduced without a sequence, e.g.:

```
conn.prepareStatement("insert into \"MixedCaseTable\" " +
"(IDENT) VALUES (1)",
new int[]{1});
```

This would mean that this flavor of prepareStatement is completely broken for all tables names and column names that are not all caps -- any names that need to be quoted.

Now, I didn't decompile Oracle's driver because that would presumably be illegal or something, but I have a friend who told me that he traced this problem down to the JDBC driver - class AutoKeyInfo, method getTableName, and the problem has to do with forcing the SQL to all caps for everything.

The workaround would consist of using the other version of prepareStatement (with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS), get the ROWID, and then retrieve the row from that, but that's an extra query, and that just seems asinine.

Am I missing something? Surely a bug this big could not have been around for years?

Comment: Not that it's a comfort, however [Oracle themselves say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129): _Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by SQL*Plus, but they may not be valid when using other tools that manage database objects._ Sadly, that may make this (in case it is a) bug a low prio or even "won't fix" :-/

Comment: Oracle does not use getGeneratedKeys directly instead of that they use returning clause construct. `insert into "MixedCaseTable" (IDENT) values(MYSEQ.nextval) returning IDENT into :outbindvar`. On contrary this is not supported by JDBC. SQL statements can not have out parameters. It looks like Oracle has to parse and modify SQL statement on client side before sending it into the database and something bad happens during this parsing. Try to wrap it and turn it into callable statements. Definitely this looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Joachim and ibre5041! I guess mixed-case table names are just not fully supported in the Oracle world -- that's amazing to me. You learn something new every day.